# How to assign range of integers in for loop using matlab and exclude a number in that range?

Tags: matlab

I would like to have a for loop with 1:25 range but I do not want the for loop to go through number 23 in that range

in another format; I want it like this 1:22 24:25 
is it doable this way?

please help

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can write:

```
for num = [1:22 24:25]
    % do something with num
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
for idx=1:25
    if idx==23, continue, end
    disp(num2str(idx));
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an alternative:

```
skip = [23];
for idx = 1:25
   if ~any(idx == skip)
       %// Your code here
   end
end
```

I think it's more readable than using `[1:22 24:25]` as your loop variable as you can see clearly and quickly which numbers are being skipped (unless `[1:22 24:25]` is a variable getting generated elsewhere in which case I would go with that method), it avoids `continue` which is controversial and it's easy to add other numbers to skip (i.e. `skip = [7, 18, 23]` etc...)